# Android Gradle errors after update to 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources, android-build

I did an update for Android Studio this morning , now it's on Android Studio 3.2

```
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0.
```

before the update the project was working fine now i got errors building it :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Android resource linking failed
warn: removing resource (myAppId)/content_main_photos without required default value.
app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:23: error: resource string/fgmt_titre_drawer (aka (myAppId):string/fgmt_titre_drawer) not found.
...
...
...
```

i have tired to clean and rebuild , restart and invalidate cache but nothing is working.

what is the problem ?

Comment: please can you share your gradle plugin version.

Comment: Gradle Version : 4.6
Android Plugin Version : 3.2.0

Comment: i got this error for many strings , i didn't change anything before , it's happened just right after thr update of Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to string resource translations; just fixed a similar error yesterday ...where `values/strings.xml` were lacking a string resource, which `values-de/strings.xml` contained. that "default value" is being defined in `values/strings.xml` (which is the "default translation").

you'd have to search all translations for `fgmt_titre_drawer` and add it, where it is missing.

Answer (score 2):

> resource string/fgmt_titre_drawer (aka
>   (myAppId):`string/fgmt_titre_drawer`) **not found**.

There is a missing string called: `fgmt_titre_drawer`.

Go to `res/strings.xml` and declare a string called `fgmt_titre_drawer`:

```
<string name="fgmt_titre_drawer">YourText</string>
```

Then rebuild the project and it will work.

Comment: it's there , it's not missing , the project was working fine just right before the update.

Comment: Can you show us the `activity_main.xml` xml code where `fgmt_titre_drawer` is used? I'm suspecting that the string is used wrong. or maybe other issues which needs the codes to be checked.

Comment: <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fgmt_titre_drawer"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: Seems fine. How about the code in `strings.xml`? Did you check it? I've faced the same error too and it was because of something else tho.

Answer (score 0):

Check for string resource `string/fgmt_titre_drawer`. If there is compile error please try to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar problem few weeks ago after we've bump our build tools version to 28.0.3. We have some limitations which don't allow put strings in default values folder. There is answer here but maybe you need something that allow you not to think about you didn't add some values in default folder :)

I wrote the gradle script for generating missing resources. This script generates only strings, styles, integers etc (everything from "values" folders). Feel free to open PR for generating other resource types :)

https://github.com/gerra/MissingResources

Everything you need is in `missing_res_generator.gradle` file.